# gcc version issue on CentOS system

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, cmake, centos

I am working on CentOS system which has gcc version 4.4.7. For installation of clang it needs the gcc version to be 4.7 or above.
Hence I installed devtools and after running :

```
scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash
gcc -v
```

It shows the version to be 4.7
but `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` still shows it to be 4.4.7
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is that a cached value from a run of cmake from outside the devtoolset-1.1 environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake prefers the default compiler of the system, even when another compiler appears in PATH first.
However you can set CC and CXX to force a different compiler.

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake ..
```